# How to add bannerAds add in to pop up view swift 4

Tags: swift, uiview, banner-ads

App crash when banner ads into pop up view

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint
>   reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's
>   illegal. constraint:

```
viewads.addConstraints(
            [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .bottom,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                                attribute: .top,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0),
             NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0)
            ])   popview.addSubview(bannerView)
```

banner add in to pop view

Comment: Add more code please. How do you create `bannerView`?

Comment: Are you using google AdMob? Maybe what you need is to create an interstitial instead of a banner, but it's not very clear for me what you need, could you please provide more info and code?

Comment: yes i'm using google admob.  i'm adding my banner in custom view so that when it comes to set a banner constraint programatically at that time it  don't set in my custom view , it only set in main view

Comment: Please update the code so that I can see what you need

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to add a banner to my app:

**1. Add this to your ViewDidLoad**

```
            bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
            addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
            bannerView.delegate = self
            bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716" //This is the test ID, always use this to test your app.

            bannerView.rootViewController = self
            bannerView.load(GADRequest())
```

**2. Add these functions, you can find them on the google AdMob website, I personally suggest to add them all, before I added them my code didn't work**

```
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            // In iOS 11, we need to constrain the view to the safe area.
            positionBannerViewFullWidthAtBottomOfSafeArea(bannerView)
        }
        else {
            // In lower iOS versions, safe area is not available so we use
            // bottom layout guide and view edges.
            positionBannerViewFullWidthAtBottomOfView(bannerView)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - view positioning
    @available (iOS 11, *)
    func positionBannerViewFullWidthAtBottomOfSafeArea(_ bannerView: UIView) {
        // Position the banner. Stick it to the bottom of the Safe Area.
        // Make it constrained to the edges of the safe area.
        let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            guide.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.leftAnchor),
            guide.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.rightAnchor),
            guide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.bottomAnchor)
            ])
    }

    func positionBannerViewFullWidthAtBottomOfView(_ bannerView: UIView) {
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                              attribute: .leading,
                                              relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: view,
                                              attribute: .leading,
                                              multiplier: 1,
                                              constant: 0))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                              attribute: .trailing,
                                              relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: view,
                                              attribute: .trailing,
                                              multiplier: 1,
                                              constant: 0))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                              attribute: .bottom,
                                              relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                                              attribute: .top,
                                              multiplier: 1,
                                              constant: 0))
    }


    /// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
        addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
        bannerView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            bannerView.alpha = 1
        })
    }

    /// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
                didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that a full-screen view will be presented in response
    /// to the user clicking on an ad.
    func adViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillPresentScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view will be dismissed.
    func adViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillDismissScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view has been dismissed.
    func adViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidDismissScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
    /// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
    func adViewWillLeaveApplication(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillLeaveApplication")
    }
```

Don't forget to set `GADBannerViewDelegate` in your class.